# Launching a client-side compiler from a browser via anything

Tags: python, html, compiler-construction, cross-browser

I'm currently working on a web based educational tool where student can look at example of code in a browser and edit the code in the browser. I have been trying to implement a system where by they can interface with a client-side compiler and run/debug the code with in the browser. The more research I do the more I see that browsers are designed against letting this happen because of the security issues that this creates. I was wondering is there any way to run a compiler locally i.e via a extension or ajax or some other method.

The aim is to accommodate as many languages as possible although we are starting of with python.

I'm aware that I could run the script server side and display the output however This is limited in application(to my knowledge), Specifically regarding to GUIs.

Comment: Python interpreter  its on server side 
http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs262/CourseRev/apr2012/Unit/3001/Nugget/47004

Comment: As an attacker, I will be very interested in the how you can do this, since I will be able to paste an arbitrary code and let it compiles and runs on the client side, without any guarantee of restriction whatsoever.

Comment: The idea is that the student is the only one with access to the document bar the teacher its not an open forum where anyone can post anything and it runs on everyones pc. I understand that there are a lot of potential security risks involved but I feel that if created properly it will have no more risks that an ide linked to an svn.

Comment: @SRN This would work fine in some cases but say if the student wanted to draw with the turtle module how would they see what there code creates.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something like this (though not a compiler) for a [project of mine](https://github.com/nibrahim/tomobi). It had to download and process a resource given its URL into a format that could be read on a kindle. It's not exactly similar to yours since I had a browser plugin (rather than a web page) which triggered the operation and even that was not allowed to "leave" the browser.

In the end, I was forced to write a little app that ran on the client side which the plugin submitted the URL to and then processed.

The setup is something like this

```
browser plugin (via ajax) <------> web app on client ----> compiler/etc.
```

The browser sends the code snippet (in your case, a URL in mine) to a web app that runs on the local machine listening on some port (say `9999`). It can access local resources and so can actually run the code and then return something to the browser which can then render it.

In my case, the browser sends a JSON string to the web app which just contains a URL. The web app fetches the resource, processes it and converts it into a `.mobi` file which the kindle can read and then drops it into a directory. The result of the conversion (success/failure) and the location of the converted file is sent back to the browser which informs you that it's done.

I don't think you can write a plugin that directly accesses the compiler. It'll have to communicate with a local app. The setup is complicated for non technical users (look at the README on my project) but it works.

Comment: Thats pretty neat :).

So a possible solution is to create a plugin that when the user hits compile/run the plugin sends the information to an application running on the desktop that then access and compiles that piece of code? Or are you suggesting i create a plugin that directly access an installed compiler and launches the code.

I was operating under the premise that a plugin could not directly launch an desktop application. Have i got this wrong?